# document.getElementById with SMARTY Variable

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I need to get the `.innerHTML` out of a div that has a SMARTY Variable as ID.

It looks like this:

```
<div id="{$products_data.IMAGE}">{$products_data.QTY}</div>
```

What i tried so far and is not working for some reason is this:

```
test = document.getElementById("{$products_data.IMAGE}").innerHTML;
```

Anyone has any experience with SMARTY and Javascript?

Comment: I suspect the `id` does not look like that once the page has loaded.  Try looking at the `div` in developer tools.

Comment: This code would be fine actually. This will only work when the javascript is in the same .tpl as the smarty code is, is this the case? Or are you loading the JavaScript from another file? JavaScript can't read the Smarty variable in that case.

Comment: Well, actually the two are not in the same .tpl. It seems very logical that it is not tworking then because when they get together the javascript is looking for a smarty variable that has already been converted to an HTML output at this point. I have no idea how to bring them together then.

Comment: You can just do <script>Your stuff</script> at the end of the .tpl file. Or is this some strange scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global JavaScript variable in the .tpl file to pass the value from Smarty.

In the **.tpl** file:

```
<script>
// Global variables 
var smartyDivId = "{$products_data.IMAGE}";
</script>
```

In the **.js** file:

```
if (typeof smartyDivId != undefined) {
    test = document.getElementById(smartyDivId).innerHTML;
}
```